# how to rewrite url in route codeigniter menually

Tags: codeigniter

i want to rewrite url in codeigniter

i have many country when i click the any country name  the page display  country detail and make this country link in url  as

```
http://localhost/worldtimeserver/Country/detail/india
```

but i want show link  in url  as

```
http://localhost/worldtimeserver/Country/india
```

i have 240 country  and and give them link for display detail of those country

i want to rewrite the url for those country  but i don,t know how it is 
please help me i'm new in CI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following in your `routes.php` file

```
$route['Country/(:any)'] = 'Country/detail/$1';
```

Now when you will browse `http://localhost/worldtimeserver/Country/india` then it will take into `Country` controller's `detail` method with following parameter

Comment: thanks a lot dear i'm very glade to you response me very Innergatic